# preg_replace not working inside loop

Tags: php, regex, rss, preg-replace

I am parsing an RSS feed and I'm trying to remove a specific bit of one of its items so it's not displayed.

```
<pre>M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q1.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q10.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q11.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q12.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q13.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q14.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q15.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q2.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q3.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q4.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q5.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q6.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q7.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q8.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/html-en/quests/_419_GetaPet/419_q9.htm M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/scripts/quests/_128_PailakaSongofIceandFire.java M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/scripts/quests/_129_PailakaDevilsLegacy.java M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/scripts/quests/_144_PailakaInjuredDragon.java M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/scripts/quests/_311_ExpulsionOfEvilSpirits.java M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/scripts/quests/_312_TakeAdvantageOfTheCrisis.java M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/scripts/quests/_642_APowerfulPrimevalCreature.java M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/scripts/quests/_643_RiseAndFallOfTheElrokiTribe.java M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/stats/items/15400-15499.xml M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/stats/items/700-799.xml M /WITHHELD/WITHHELD/dist/gameserver/data/stats/npc/22600-22699.xml</pre>
```

Essentially I want to remove the **`<pre>`** tags and anything in between them.

I am using the following **`preg_replace`**:

```
preg_replace("/(<pre>.*<\/pre>)/", "", $str);
```

It **does work** when I have the string that contains the bit I want to remove as a **static variable**, but **it does not** when I try to **replace it inside the RSS output loop**:

```
    $i = 1;

    foreach($rs['items'] as &$item) {
    $arr = array($i);
    $a = array_fill_keys($arr, (string)$item['description']);
    $desc = (string)$a[$i];
    $desc = preg_replace("/(<pre>.*<\/pre>)/", "", $desc);

    echo "\t<li><a href=\"$item[link]\">(".$i.")".$item['title']."</a><br />";
    echo $desc;
    echo "</li>\n";
    $i++;
    }
```

You can probably tell by the poorly written piece of code above that I am at a complete loss and have tried numerous ways to make this work.

The **description ($desc)** node remains unchanged, even when I try to save the entire output as a variable **($htm)** and then run preg_replace.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, don't use regex to parse HTML, use DOM parser instead. see http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: What if you enable `s` flag `/(<pre>.*?<\/pre>)/s`?

Comment: @Toto I tried saving the entire parsed string as a variable and then parsing it with DOM and it didn't work either.

Comment: @revo Just tried it, no luck. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the change, you gotta pass by reference using it as **&$item** instead of **$item** like this:

```
foreach($rs['items'] as &$item) //Pass by reference using "&"
{
 $arr = array($i);
 $a = array_fill_keys($arr, (string)$item['description']);
 $desc = (string)$a[$i];
 $desc = preg_replace("/(<pre>.*<\/pre>)/", "", $desc);

 $htm .= "\t<li><a href=\"$item[link]\">(".$i.")".$item['title']."</a><br />";
 $htm .= replace($desc);
 $htm .= "</li>\n";
 $i++;
 $item['description'] = $desc; //Add this
}
```

That should work. Lemme know if it still doesn't.

**EDITED:**
Just add **$item['description'] = $desc;** at the end of the loop as above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, that did not fix it.

Comment: @Kalinia - that is again because you've to use pass by reference. You have to add "&" to variable $a and $desc like &$a and &$desc inside the foreach loop. Can you give me sample values of $rs?

Comment: Do I add '&' to where the variables are defined or further into the code? - $rs is essentially the 'Get' function in the RSS parser's library that I am using. It can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/xii2kFC9

Comment: @Kalinia - Nevermind, just save it in the end. I updated the code above in my post. That should work (Y)

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid :(

Comment: Can you check the value of $desc before replacing? The reason could be that you're saving it wrong in the first place?

Comment: I just did and it looks fine prior to replacing. I am now toying around to see whether I could just remove the `<pre>` tags directly via the parser itself, but no luck so far.